# Adding line by line comments to math proofs

Tags: formatting

Is it possible to add a line by line discussion of my proof?  I'm using the Harvey Mudd college math template, so the fewest number of packages or class editing would be great.

I'm looking for the following:

equation line  comment about the proof

3+x=4          we are trying to solve for x

x=4-3          Subtract 3 from both sides

x=1            x must be one

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Please review Herbert Voss's  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)

But, one way is to use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package:

[image]

Another option to consider is to use `\intertext` (or `\shortintertext` from the `mathtools` package which yields tighter spacing):

[image]

### Code: `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    3+x &=4 && \text{we are trying to solve for } x\\
    x &=4-3 && \text{Subtract 3 from both sides}\\
    x &=1   && x \text{ must be one}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `\shortintertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\shortintertext{We are trying to solve for $x$:}
    3+x &=4 \\
\shortintertext{Subtract 3 from both sides:}
    x &=4-3 \\
\shortintertext{Hence, $x$ must be one:}
    x &=1 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alas, your link is now broken.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: Thanks for letting me know. Should be fixed now.