# Detect width of minipage environment

Tags: minipage, width, varwidth

I am using the following setup to add comments to the right of aligned equations.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\text{\footnotesize{#1}}}
\newcommand{\blurb}[2]{\begin{minipage}{#1} \footnotesize #2 \end{minipage}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{align*}
1 &= 2 \\
3 &= 4 && \comment{\lipsum[1]} \\
5 &= 6 && \blurb{4in}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

Currently, if I have a comment that is too long to keep the equation group within the text width (as in the comment for $3 = 4$), I use the `blurb` command I defined and manually tweak the `minipage` width until it's acceptable (as in the comment for $5=6$). (Maybe a better criterion for "acceptable" would be the largest `minipage` width that allows the entire equation group to sit within the text width; this is often what I end up doing because of space constraints with long equations *and* comments.)

Is there some automation so that I don't have to manually tweak my too-long `comment`s to `blurb`s? A solution as described in the question title seems unlikely because it would need a width parameter to define a `minipage`, but the contents of the `minipage` determine what that width parameter should be. But maybe there's another way to achieve the same result.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use wide lengthy comments on the side of the equations This makes the body of the equations flush left, which doesn't look very good. You should the `\intertext{…}` or `\shortintertex{…}` instead.

Comment: ...as seen in [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665/5764) and [Adding line by line comments to math proofs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47687/5764).

Comment: @Bernard Should there be a `not` in there somewhere?

Comment: The main problem is that LaTeX doesn't know how wide the remainder is until after the comment is formatted.  You could use \tikzmark and pgfpagenodes to compute the width using two runs.