# avoid eq. # on \shortintertext{} from mathtools

Tags: equations, comments, mathtools

Does anyone know of an elegant way to avoid having to manually put an `\nonumber` at the end of  `\shortintertext{}` when it is at the last line? As illustrated by the parts of the minimal working example (MWE) below that is commented out by a `%`.

I am very happy to use `\shortintertext{}` from [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools?lang=en). `\shortintertext{}` do not produce a equation number, which I like, but if I use `\shortintertext{}` as the last thing in an `{align}` equation block `\shortintertext{}` produces an extra equation number (as this, see blow for MWE)
[image: \shortintertext{} too many equation numbers]

It also seems as `\shortintertext{}` produces extra line spacing …

MWE (inspired by [this SE example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47691/22939));

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\shortintertext{\color{gray}  We are trying to solve for $x$}
    3+x &=4\\
\shortintertext{\color{gray} Subtract 3 from both sides:} 
    x &=4-3 \
 \shortintertext{\color{gray} Hence, $x$ must be 1:}
    x &=1 
 \shortintertext{\color{gray} Some comments on the conclussion} % \nonumber
\end{align} %  \vspace{-3.4 em}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first and last `\shortintertext` should be normal text outside `align`.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for your feedback. I tried playing around with having my first and last comment outside `align`. However, there's a special line spacing for `\shortintertext{}` so that when I take comments outside `align` those comments do not have the same spacing as the rest of the equation comments. Maybe I shouldn't use `\shortintertext{}` at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{compactequations}
 {\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt plus 2pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{2pt plus 2pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt plus 2pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{2pt plus 2pt}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactequations}
\noindent\textcolor{gray}{We are trying to solve for $x$}
\begin{align}
    3+x &=4\\
\intertext{\color{gray} Subtract 3 from both sides:} % \nonumber
    x &=4-3 \\
 \intertext{\color{gray} Hence, $x$ must be 1:}
    x &=1
\end{align}
\textcolor{gray}{Some comments on the conclusion}
\end{compactequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without aligning at the equals signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newenvironment{compactequations}
 {\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt plus 2pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{2pt plus 2pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt plus 2pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{2pt plus 2pt}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactequations}
\noindent We are trying to solve for $x$
\begin{equation}
    3+x=4
\end{equation}
Subtract 3 from both sides:
\begin{equation}
    x=4-3
\end{equation}
Hence, $x$ must be 1:
\begin{equation}
    x=1 
\end{equation}
Some comments on the conclusion
\end{compactequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write up an elaborate answer. It does solve the issue, but it also adds quite a bit of code-customization to each `align` environment (and preamble). I've played around with having an ` \nonumber` after the last `\shortintertext{}`, inside my align environment, accompanied by an `\vspace{-3.4 em}` after the align environment, i.e. `\end{align}  \vspace{-3.4 em}`. I've imagined a solution using a feature of `mathtools` I wasn't aware of or some other package that did the job with less customization.  Your answer kinda give me a sense of the issue at hand.