# In a text, how to align text pieces together and equations together?

Tags: equations

I am preparing a LaTeX document. I am stuck in a problem where I wanted to make my document somehow look like the attached image. The text all together aligned to the left of the page, and equations aligned together at the center. I have made too many trials but failed. Any help? [image: I want my text looks like this]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  You can use `align`/`gather` environments along with `\intertext{}`.  Two such examples [Adding line by line comments to math proofs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47687/4301) and [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665/4301).  Do either of these answer your question?

Comment: Is there a real need for aligning those three equations at the equals sign?

Comment: @egreg no need to align equal signs.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you very much, it worked by using {mathtools} package and shortintertext command. Thanks.

Comment: @AliM.EidBashabsheh So, where's the problem?

Comment: @egreg: I think we can close this as a duplicate. Also, for longer text as in your example, using `\intertext{}` is probable better than `\shorintertext{}`.

Comment: @egreg the problem was in aligning texts to the left and equation at the center, but now its all solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what the question is asking. I'd simply type in the text with `equation` environments for the three equations.

If you really want to align the equations, you can use `\intertext` and `align`, but the result is not pretty.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % image uses Times

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{d#1}{d#2}}


\begin{document}

\section{No alignment}
\setcounter{equation}{57} % to emulate the picture

For the PMSM with multiple pairs of poles, the electrical speed relates
to the mechanical speed by
\begin{equation}\label{elec-mech}
\omega_e = Z_p \omega_m
\end{equation}
where $Z_p$ denotes the pair of poles of the PMSM. The rotation of motor
could be described by the following dynamic equation:
\begin{equation}\label{dynamic-m}
J_m\der{\omega_m}{t} = T_e - B_v\omega_m - T_L
\end{equation}
with $J_m$ denoting the total inertia, $B_v$ viscous friction and $T_L$
load torque. Replacing the mechanical speed $\omega_m$ with electrical
speed $\omega_e$ in~\eqref{dynamic-m} gives
\begin{equation}\label{dynamic-e}
\der{\omega_e}{t} = \frac{Z_p}{J_m}\biggl(T_e - \frac{B_v}{Z_p}\omega_e - T_L\biggr)
\end{equation}

\section{With alignment}
\setcounter{equation}{57} % to emulate the picture

For the PMSM with multiple pairs of poles, the electrical speed relates
to the mechanical speed by
\begin{align}
\omega_e &= Z_p \omega_m \label{elec-mech-A} \\
\intertext{where $Z_p$ denotes the pair of poles of the PMSM. The rotation of motor
could be described by the following dynamic equation:}
J_m\der{\omega_m}{t} &= T_e - B_v\omega_m - T_L \label{dynamic-m-A} \\
\intertext{with $J_m$ denoting the total inertia, $B_v$ viscous friction and $T_L$
load torque. Replacing the mechanical speed $\omega_m$ with electrical
speed $\omega_e$ in~\eqref{dynamic-m-A} gives}
\der{\omega_e}{t} &= \frac{Z_p}{J_m}\biggl(T_e - \frac{B_v}{Z_p}\omega_e - T_L\biggr)
  \label{dynamic-e-A}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that my problem was I didn't use these commands when using intertext command:

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % image uses Times

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{d#1}{d#2}}